# Sync job between servers

Tags: node.js, socket.io, synchronization

I have a p2p network with some nodejs servers using socket.io. Every 10 seconds one random server should execute a job, so the servers have to communicate who will do the job.

Right now I use the logik like this:

```
public generate() {     
    setInterval(() => {
        this.randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
        // console.log("send rand number to all gens:", this.randomNumber);
        this.generatorConnectionsInfo.forEach((gen: IGeneratorConnectionsInfos) => {
            // console.log("send rand", this.randomNumber, "to", gen.peer);
            gen.socket.emit("rand", this.randomNumber);
        });
        this.generating = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("do the job");                
        }, (8 * 1000);
    }, (10 * 1000);
}
```

Each server is listing for the numbers of the other servers. If one of them is lower than the own one, the timeout will be stopped:

```
public checkGeneration(rand: number) {
    console.log("got", rand, "from gen");
    if (rand > this.randomNumber) {
        console.log("generation got canceled");
        clearTimeout(this.generating);
    }       
}
```

So only the server having the highest number will do the job. The problem is to sync them in time so the intervals start at the same time.

Comment: Synchronize your clocks.  Send out a message to all servers that announce what time the next interval should be started.  Program them all to start the interval at that time.

Comment: But, there probably are much better ways to solve this issue.  Why not just have one master server that is responsible for randomly picking one of the servers to execute a job and then send them a message to execute it.  If you don't want it to be random, you can even rotate it around so all servers get a fair number of jobs.

Comment: @jfriend00 Right now I am using a method mentioned in your first comment: after a node connected he will get the time when the next interval should start. It will generate a timeout with the difference of the given time and the current time.

To your second post: a master server is a "single point of failure" i want to avoid. All servers should be equal. Rotating is also bad because servers can crash so a deadlock will be the result.

Comment: Intervals can drift over time in Javascript - they are not precise timers.  Assuming a `setInterval()` across multiple servers will be regularly synchronized with all the other servers over a long duration of time is not a good assumption.

Comment: So maybe I can use the `setInterval` method but have to sync up the clocks from time to time. Maybe I have to dive deeper because this sounds like a known problem.